# The set of all x for that $f_n(x)$ a measurable function converges is measurable as well?

Tags: measure-theory

$f_{n}: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of measurable functions on $\Omega$.
Is $\{ x\in \Omega : f_{n}(x)$ converges $\}$ a measurable set?

I wanted to show it with the monoton convergence theorem but thats only valid for not negative and monotonic sequences. Is there another theorem I'm missing for a beautiful solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is true. Let $f$ be a funcion such that $f_n \to f$ and let $E=\{ x \in \Omega: (f_n) \: \mathrm{converges} \}$. If $x \in E$, then $f_n(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence, that is, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\varepsilon$, for all $m,n > N$. In particular, if we choose $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ then $x \in E$ is equivalent to $$x \in \bigcap_{\varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}^+}\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{m=N+1}^{\infty} \{ x \in \Omega:|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\varepsilon \}.$$ Since by hypothesis the set $\{ x \in \Omega: |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\varepsilon \}$ is measurable, and the countable union and countable intersection of measurable sets is measurable, we are done.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Note that $\liminf f_n$ and $\limsup f_n$ are both measurable, so $g=\liminf f_n - \limsup f_n$ is measurable as well. The set $A:=\{x \in \Omega\ | \ f_n(x) \text{ converges}\}$ is just equal to $B:=\{x \in \Omega\ \ | g(x)=0\}$. The only thing that is left to show is that $B$ is measurable.

Can you show $B$ is a mearuable set?

Comment: g is build of measurable functions and is therefore measurable and therefore the preimage $g^{-1}(0)=B$ is measurable?

Comment: @Erdbeer0815 that is right!

Comment: Thank you. I like your method! We also need to discuss 0 is in Boreal sigma-algebra. That can be shown by the intersection of open sets (0, 1/n). Right?

Comment: @Jonathen you mean closed sets $[0, 1/n]$? Then yes!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\{x\in\Omega: f_{n}(x)~\text{converge}\}=\{x\in\Omega:\liminf_{n}f_{n}(x)=\limsup_{n}f_{n}(x)\}$. Now the monotone properties apply to both $\liminf_{n}f_{n}$ and $\limsup_{n}f_{n}$ to claim that they are measurable.